# Is there any way to view iOS device logs on the Terminal?

Tags: macos, ios, command-line, logs

Is there any way to view iOS device logs on the Terminal?

Comment: XCode free by Apple provides a graphical interface to pull logs and other info from your device. It's not a way on the terminal but just another option :)

Answer (score 9):

i believe [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) is what you're looking for. github repo can be found [here](https://github.com/libimobiledevice)

it's a cross-platform lib talking to iDevices with no jailbrake needed. just use console command

> $ idevicesyslog

you can install it via homebrew or compile from sources

**macOS install via homebrew**

> $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
>
> $ brew install -v --devel --fresh automake autoconf libtool wget libimobiledevice
>
> $ brew install -v --HEAD --fresh --build-from-source ideviceinstaller

**linux**

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice ideviceinstaller

Comment: Please explain what exactly this is, and what operations it performs to help the user. Things to include may be usage of the commands, what it accesses, and how it is relevant to the question - From Review

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can see iOS system logs from the the Mac command line.

Install Apple Configurator. It has an official helper tool to show the log files and perform other handy tasks.

```
cfgutil syslog
```

The help command is quite useful and you can install it from the "Install Automation Tools..." menu item once you run Apple Configurator 2

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt as I have never gone looking for IOS device logs but there are apps out there (iExplorer comes to mind, there are others) that let you explore the file system of a connected IOS device and/or the contents of iTunes backups of the device. That may allow you to do what you want.